# Set Default Value of User Entity Reference to logged in user

Tags: entities, users, tokens

I have a Drupal 8 installation that has a user reference field and I would like the currently logged in user to be the default value for the field. I believe in Drupal 7 I would've used the [current-user:name] Token for this. That functionality didn't seem to show up when I installed Token for D8.

Comment: What exactly are you entering? Can you check `/admin/help/token` with the Help module enabled?

Comment: That page does indeed say there is still a [current-user:name] token.

However, when I add an Entity Reference field to my content type, my "Default Value" section is only a dropdown of existing users, there is no text field to enter the token listed above.

That being said, I could use a Text field, insert the token, but that field would still need to be editable if the value needed to be changed to another user. Now my data could be a username that doesn't exist/is spelled incorrectly/etc.

Comment: Entity reference fields only reference IDs, not names. So the correct token should be the one for the current user ID. It seems you need [Field default token](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_default_token)? Also keep an eye on the issue suggested in that module https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1070878

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to make a utility module and use `hook_form_alter()` (with a switch statement on the `$form_id` you're targeting if you're targeting multiple forms) or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`. Then the following should do the job:

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function mymodule_hook_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "TARGET_FORM_ID") {
    $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $form['field_user']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = User::load($current_user->id());;
  }
}
```